# R gt_table adjust row height

Tags: r

I am outputting a table using `gt_table`. An example of my output is here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/z15v4.png

I need to decrease the "padding" or "white space" around the row height so that the final output is as concise as I can make it.  I have looked through the `gt_table` documentation and have not been able to find a way to adjust the row heights.  Specifically I have looked at the `tab_style` and `tab_option` keywords, but couldn't make any of the keywords work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done with the `data_row.padding` parameter in `tab_options`.

```
library(gt)

gt(head(iris)) %>%
  tab_options(data_row.padding = px(1))
```

[image: Plot]